# SandBoxing Python : exec with __builtins__ set as None, Accessing a method on datetime leads to a KeyError exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to limit random code execution by doing the below in Py 3.11.4 on M1 chip -:

```py
import datetime
import io
import traceback
from contextlib import redirect_stderr, redirect_stdout

from typing import Dict

SAFE_BUILTINS = ['abs', 'all', 'any', 'chr', 'dict', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'filter', 'float', 'hasattr', 'int', 'isinstance', 'len', 'list', 'map', 'max', 'min', 'object', 'pow', 'print', 'range', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'slice', 'sorted', 'str', 'tuple', 'type', 'zip']


def _get_restricted_locals() -> Dict[str, object]:

    _locals: Dict[str, object] = {"datetime": datetime, "timedelta": datetime.timedelta}

    safe_builtins = {
        k: __builtins__.__dict__.get(k)
        for k in SAFE_BUILTINS   # type: ignore
    }
    _locals = {**_locals, **safe_builtins}

    return _locals


def execute_python(code: str):
    out = io.StringIO()
    err = io.StringIO()

    _locals = _get_restricted_locals()

    try:
        with redirect_stdout(out), redirect_stderr(err):
            exec(
                code,
                {"__builtins__": None},
                _locals,
            )
    except SyntaxError as e:
        print("SYNTAX ERROR", e)
        tbk = traceback.format_exc()
        print(tbk)

    except Exception as e:
        print("RUNTIME ERROR", e)
        tbk = traceback.format_exc()
        print(tbk)

    finally:
        stdout = out.getvalue()
        stderr = err.getvalue()

    return {
        "stdout": stdout,
        "stderr": stderr,
    }


# Usage

# The below doesn't work because of `.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`. If we remove the same, then the snippet executes.

_code: str = """
begin_date = (datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
print(begin_date, end_date)
"""

# Will fail (comment out the `.strftime` for a successful execution)
print(execute_python(code=_code))
```

- How can we make changes to the above snippet to make it work with `strftime`?
- Would like to know and understand more as to what happens when we do `object.method()` on Python? -> It tries to access the `__dict__` and `getattr`. What next?

I tried few ideas but not sure. Looks like because we're adjusting the [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#:%7E:text=As%20an%20implementation%20detail%2C%20most,by%20alternate%20implementations%20of%20Python.), it removes the `__import__` and lot of other things critical for Python to work.

Here's the **traceback**

```py
RUNTIME ERROR '__import__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing_exec.py", line 279, in execute_python
    exec(
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
KeyError: '__import__'
```

Comment: Sandboxing Python effectively is not really something that fits in a Stack Overflow question - it's a topic people start whole OSS projects over (and often eventually abandon those projects after they're found to have loopholes). Can you write a title that focuses more narrowly on the specific problem with the individual approach, so people looking for more general sandboxing don't end up here?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried to reword the same. @CharlesDuffy I agree that sand-boxing Python is not really easy at all, I am still curious to understand why Python is complaining? Thanks

Comment: Define "fail." What actually happens? If you get an error message, post it including the traceback.

Comment: My apologies, forgot to add the traceback. I've updated the post. Thanks

Comment: Sandboxing Python does not work, period. Abandon this approach and sandbox the whole machine, i.e. use containers or VMs.

Comment: Thank you for adding the traceback -- that's a problem, indeed, and I'll be curious to see what answers this gets. Personally, I'd probably take an AST-analysis approach (but you'd need to be allowing only a _very_ restrictive subset to have any hope of success).

Comment: Just want to share what one can try -: Went with exec and using ephemeral MicroVMs for production (TTL for these VMs is typically less than 200 msec)

Answer (score 2):

It complains because you've overwritten `__builtins__` with a thing that doesn't have `__import__`, and [`datetime.date.strftime()` internally tries to import `time.strftime` to do its thing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/67a91f78e4395148afcc33e5cd6f3f0a9623e63a/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L1741-L1749):

```
PyObject *strftime = _PyImport_GetModuleAttrString("time", "strftime");
if (strftime == NULL) goto Done;
// ...
```

(see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/309efb39dc005a834bb67e9a6f27b6689f00ec9d/Python/import.c#L2989-L3015) for the mechanism that `_PyImport_GetModuleAttrString` internally uses to find an `__import__` function.)

If you replace your `{'__builtins__': None}` with

```
{"__builtins__": {"__import__": lambda m, *args: print("importing", m)}}
```

you'll see an attempt to import `time` – and since `print` returns `None`, that `_PyImport_GetModuleAttrString` returns None, and `strftime` will do nothing:

```
importing time
importing time
2023-10-19 2023-10-26
None
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot for passing by. I know it's importing time (followed the internal src of datetime) but even if we add time to the locals, it will not stop it from trying to import, right?

Comment: Unfortunately not – that C code doesn't know about your Python locals (nor does it know about `sys.modules`, so pre-importing `time` won't help either).

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the Cython src! It explains the what's happening part. Thanks.